# Where is HTMLImageElemen.src handled for HTMLImageElemen?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, promise

Consider the following code that detect if the image src is valid in angular

```
    isImage: function(src) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var image = new Image();
        image.onerror = function(data) {
          console.log(data, "error");
            deferred.resolve([false, src]);
        };
        image.onload = function(data) {
          console.log(data, "success");
            deferred.resolve([true, src]);
        };

        image.src = "some_valid_image_url"
        setTimeout(function() {
          image.src = "some_valid_image_url"
        }, 5000)

        return deferred.promise;
    }



isImage("some_valid_image_url").then(function() {console.log("return")})
```

If I run the code above my console will print

```
success
```

2 times

but

```
return
```

is print 1 time

Seems like somewhere there is a change handler watching the property?

My question is where is the change handler for `.src` residing and why is `.then` resolve only once?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is where is the change handler for `.src` residing

`javascript` at Question sets `onerror` and `onload` handlers for `<img>` element. `.src` property of `<img>` is set twice, calling `onerror` or `onload` event handler twice.

> and why is .then resolve only once?

A `Promise` can be resolved or rejected at most once. `.then()` is called once chained to `Promise` object.

Comment: But where is it detecting `src` is changing?

Comment: @Jal At `load` and `error` events. _"If an error occurs while trying to load or render the image, and an onerror event handler has been configured to handle the [`error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/error) event, that event handler will get called."_ See [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Comment: See also [load](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-load) event.